# How to access a topic in a ROS2 action server

Tags: c++, ros2

In an ROS2 action server callback function, I need to access data which is published on some ROS topic. How can I achieve this, in a straightforward and clean way.

Subscribing to the wanted topic in the action server would require a returning callback, which is not straightforward (in my opinion).
Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Accessing data from a topic should pretty much always be done via a callback. Why do you not think this is straightforward?

Comment: If an action request is received, the action-callback is executed. In this action-callback I need to access the data received from _another_ callback. The answer provided by @fet.atas seems to work though.

Answer (score 0):

> Subscribing to the wanted topic in the action server would require a returning callback, which is not straightforward (in my opinion). Is there an easier way to achieve this?

you can create a global variable where the type is ros message that you are subscribing, then in callback update the variable with latest received message, in your action server you can use the the global variable, You might wanted to use a mutex if the ros message you are receiving is something like image or pointcloud message

Comment: Thanks, I did that and it worked. However, I wonder if I have to lock this global variable somehow when writing it.

Comment: yes, when updating and accessing data of the variable use mutex lock